# Spring Cloud Bus

Tags: spring-cloud

I see that currently Spring Cloud Bus uses rabbit.  Is there the possibility that it might be ported to kafka (http://kafka.apache.org) at some point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely!  Pull requests welcome!  The bus was made with spring integration so other technologies may be used.  [Spring Integration Kafka](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-kafka) was just released 4 days ago.

Comment: I noticed that spring-cloud-starter-bus-kafka was added, but unable to find    kafka/zookeeper host and port properties - the readme still says only amqp is implemented.  Is this port completed?

Comment: @TimDavidson it is. The documentation isn't. Any documentation would be here: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for